# Utf-8 encoding visual studios decimal value

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2017, hex

Hello I am trying to get a decimal value as statement [here](https://stevemorse.org/hebrew/utf8.html?charset=1); for example,

```
int n = 50048;
std::stringstream ss;
ss << std::hex << n;
```

should return the hex `c380` which it works fine, but when I try to convert that into a character it returns the wrong character. Everything returns correct up until `c3xx`.

```
ss << hexi;
ss >> std::hex >> value;
char temp = value;
```

Comment: it's not clear to me what you are trying to do.

Comment: @RSahu if take a decimal like the one above itll return its hex i should be able to reverse that hex to its corresponding character but its doesnt up until you hit c3xx

Comment: How do you "convert back" ?

Comment: Show us how you try to convert it into a character.

Comment: @ZDF I edited to show that

Comment: @Jarod42 please refresh

Comment: Two bytes do not fit into one char.

Comment: You probably want wchar_t. You should tell us more about what you're trying to do.

Comment: @ZDF i figured it out. The decimal was off on that chart.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
int n = 50048;
std::stringstream ss;
ss << std::hex << n;
unsigned int nn = std::stoul(ss.str(), nullptr, 16);
```